# How do I kill Wicker Grunts?

Tags: 300-march-to-glory

How do I kill Wicker Grunts in 300: March to Glory (PSP)? The game gave me a tip that I should stun them or damage them with  counterattacks, but I have no idea how to stun them. I also cannot execute counterattacks.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found good way to kill them easily. To stun, we have to perform combo X -> [] -> O, using sword and shield. If this combo hits Wicker Grunt, then it starts to be stunned and vulnerable to our normal attacks. After a few hits, Wicker Grunt should be dead.